# I have created Dotnet API that I want to deploy for free

Tags: .net, github, deployment

I wanted to deploy DotNet for my project. Can anyone please share some references that can help me upload my API?

Answer (score 0):

Azure might be a good place to start. Here is a link to the instructions from the Microsoft site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-api-management-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: it's just for one year, do you know any website which gives longtime or lifetime allowances for students?